# copy smallest files first?

Tags: shell, cp, file-copy, size

I have a large directory containing subdirectories and files that I wish to copy recursively.

Is there any way to tell `cp` that it should perform the copy operation in order of file size, so that the smallest files get copied first?

Comment: Just to be sure there's not an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) involved, can you explain *why* you want to do this?

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' - I have a lot of video files, and I'd like to quality test each directory. The smallest video will give me a quick indication of if the rest of the files are bad as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This does the whole job in one go - in all child directories, all in a single stream without any filename problems. It'll copy from smallest to largest every file you have. You will need to `mkdir ${DESTINATION}` if it doesn't already exist.

```
find . ! -type d -print0 |
du -b0 --files0-from=/dev/stdin |
sort -zk1,1n | 
sed -zn 's/^[^0-9]*[0-9]*[^.]*//p' |
tar --hard-dereference --null -T /dev/stdin -cf - |
    tar -C"${DESTINATION}" --same-order -xvf -
```

You know what, though? What this doesn't do is *empty* child directories. I could do some redirection over that pipeline, but it's just a race condition waiting to happen. Simplest is probably best. So just do this afterwards:

```
find . -type d -printf 'mkdir -p "'"${DESTINATION}"'/%p"\n' |
    . /dev/stdin
```

Or, since Gilles makes a very good point in his answer to preserve directory permissions, I should try also. I think this will do it:

```
find . -type d -printf '[ -d "'"${DESTINATION}"'/%p" ] || 
    cp "%p" -t "'"${DESTINATION}"'"\n' |
. /dev/stdin
```

I'd be willing to bet that's faster than `mkdir` anyway.

Comment: Damn you mikeserv! +1

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' I'll take that as a compliment. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 22):

Here is a quick and dirty method using `rsync`. For this example I am considering anything under 10 MB to be "small".

First transfer just the small files:

`rsync -a --max-size=10m srcdir dstdir`

Then transfer the remaining files. The previously transferred small files will not be re-copied unless they were modified.

`rsync -a srcdir dstdir`

From `man 1 rsync`

```
   --max-size=SIZE
          This  tells  rsync to avoid transferring any file that is larger
          than the specified SIZE. The SIZE value can be suffixed  with  a
          string  to  indicate  a size multiplier, and may be a fractional
          value (e.g. "--max-size=1.5m").

          This option is a transfer rule, not an exclude,  so  it  doesn’t
          affect  the  data  that  goes  into  the file-lists, and thus it
          doesn’t affect deletions.  It just limits  the  files  that  the
          receiver requests to be transferred.

          The  suffixes  are  as  follows:  "K"  (or  "KiB") is a kibibyte
          (1024), "M" (or "MiB") is a mebibyte (1024*1024),  and  "G"  (or
          "GiB")  is  a gibibyte (1024*1024*1024).  If you want the multi‐
          plier to be 1000 instead of  1024,  use  "KB",  "MB",  or  "GB".
          (Note: lower-case is also accepted for all values.)  Finally, if
          the suffix ends in either "+1" or "-1", the value will be offset
          by one byte in the indicated direction.

          Examples:    --max-size=1.5mb-1    is    1499999    bytes,   and
          --max-size=2g+1 is 2147483649 bytes.
```

Of course, the order of transfer file-by-file is not strictly smallest to largest, but I think it may be the simplest solution that meets the spirit of your requirements.

Comment: Here you get 2 copies of hard-links and soft-links are transformed into actual files for two copies of each. You'd do a lot better with `--copy-dest=DIR` and/or `--compare-dest=DIR` I think. I only know cause I had to add `--hard-dereference` myself to `tar` after posting my own answer because I was missing the links. I think `rsync` actually behaves more specific to local filesystems with those others anyway - I used to use it with USB keys and it would flood the bus unless I set a bandwidth limit. I think I should have used either of those others instead.

Comment: +1 for the "quick and dirty method".  Simpler is usually better at least for automation purposes and future maintainability.  I think this is actually pretty clean.  "Elegant" vs "kludgy" and "robust" vs "unstable" may sometimes conflict as design goals but there is a good balance that can be struck, and I think this is elegant *and* fairly robust.

Answer (score 7):

Not `cp` directly, that's well beyond its abilities. But you can arrange to call `cp` on the files in the right order.

Zsh conveniently allows sorting files by size with a [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers). Here's a zsh snippet which copies files in increasing order of size from under `/path/to/source-directory` to under `/path/to/destination-directory`.

```
cd /path/to/source-directory
for x in **/*(.oL); do
  mkdir -p /path/to/destination-directory/$x:h &&
    cp -- $x /path/to/destination-directory/$x:h
done
```

Instead of a loop, you can use the [`zcp`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zcp) function. However you need to create the destination directories first, which can be done in a cryptic oneliner.

```
autoload -U zmv; alias zcp='zmv -C'
cd /path/to/source-directory
mkdir -p **/*(/e\''REPLY=/path/to/destination-directory/$REPLY'\')
zcp -Q '**/*(.oL)' '/path/to/destination-directory/$f'
```

This doesn't preserve the ownership of the source directories. If you want that, you'll need to enlist a suitable copying program such as `cpio` or `pax`. If you do that, you don't need to call `cp` or `zcp` in addition.

```
cd /path/to/source-directory
print -rN -- **/*(^.) **/*(.oL) | cpio -0 -p /path/to/destination-directory
```

Answer (score 5):

Here I'm using a `--max-size` option for rsync, but doing it in steps of 1 MB and then the other (larger) files, with this rsync proxy script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..1024}
do
        echo Max Size $i\M
        rsync --max-size=$i\M "$@"
done
rsync "$@"
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any way to get `cp -r` to do this directly.  Since it may be an indeterminate period of time before you get a wizardly `find`/`awk` solution, here's a quick perl script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => qw(all);

use File::Find;
use File::Basename;

die "No (valid) source directory path given.\n"
    if (!$ARGV[0] || !-d -r "/$ARGV[0]");

die "No (valid) destination directory path given.\n"
    if (!$ARGV[1] || !-d -w "/$ARGV[1]");

my $len = length($ARGV[0]);
my @files;
find (
    sub {
        my $fpath = $File::Find::name;
        return if !-r -f $fpath;
        push @files, [
            substr($fpath, $len),
            (stat($fpath))[7],
        ]
    }, $ARGV[0]
);

foreach (sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } @files) {
    if ($ARGV[2]) {
        print "$_->[1] $ARGV[0]/$_->[0] -> $ARGV[1]/$_->[0]\n";
    } else {
        my $dest = "$ARGV[1]/$_->[0]";
        my $dir = dirname($dest);
        mkdir $dir if !-e $dir;
        `cp -a "$ARGV[0]/$_->[0]" $dest`;
    }
}
```

- Use this: `./whatever.pl  /src/path /dest/path`
- The arguments should be both be **absolute paths**; `~`, or anything else which the shell expands to an absolute path is fine.
- If you add a third argument (anything, except for a literal `0`), instead of copying it will print to standard out a report of what it would do, with files sizes in bytes prepended, e.g.

  ```
  4523 /src/path/file.x -> /dest/path/file.x
  12124 /src/path/file.z -> /dest/path/file.z
  ```

  Notice these are in ascending order by size.
- The `cp` command on line 34 is a literal shell command, so you can do whatever you want with the switches (I just used `-a` to preserve all traits).
- `File::Find` and `File::Basename` are both core modules, i.e. they are available in all installations of perl.

Comment: arguably, this is the only correct answer here. Or it was... the title - just changed...? My browser window is called `cp - copy smallest files first?` but the title of the post is just `copy smallest files first?` Anyway, options never hurt is my philosophy, but still, you and David are the only ones that used `cp` and you're the only one that pulled it off.

Comment: @mikeserv The only reason I used `cp` was because it's the simplest way to preserve *nix file characteristics in the (cross-platform oriented) perl.  The reason your browser bar says `cp - ` is because of a (IMO goofy) S.E. feature whereby the most popular of the selected tags appears prefixed to the actual title.

Comment: Ok, then I withdraw my compliment. Not really, you don't often see `pearl` coming out of the woodwork around here.

Answer (score 2):

another option would be to use cp with the output from du:

```
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=''
for i in $(du -sk *mpg | sort -n | cut -f 2)
do
    cp $i destination
done
IFS=$oldIFS
```

This could still be done on one line, but I split it so you can read it

Comment: Don't you at least need to do something about $IFS?

Comment: Yes...I keep assuming no one has newlines in their filenames

Comment: I know. We saner folk do make that assumption. Spaces, too, though, I think.

Comment: This also doesn't seem to handle recursion through the directory hierarchy the OP described.

Comment: @cpugeniusmv Correct...I somehow missed the recursive part....I could modify this to handle recursion, but I think at this point other answers do a better job.  I'll leave this here in case it helps someone who sees the question.

Comment: @DavidWilkins - this helps a lot.