# rsync and watch partially transferred video file

Tags: rsync, video, file-transfer

I tried to copy a large video from my server to my local device with

```
rsync -aP remotefile.mov localfile.mov
```

But the local file does not show up unless I stop the rsync process.

I can then watch the partial video with no problem in VLC.

How can I watch it while still rsyncing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the option

> --inplace
>                 This option changes how rsync transfers a file when its data needs to be updated:  instead  of  the  default
>                 method of creating a new copy of the file and moving it into place when it is complete, rsync instead writes
>                 the updated data directly to the destination file.

so this will copy whith you being able to watch it while copying:

```
rsync -aP --inplace remotefile.mov localfile.mov
```

Also worth mentioning here would be a transferlimit if you don't want to use up all the upload trafic on your server with:

```
--bwlimit=KBPS
```

And when copying folders, [copy small files first](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123789/20661) with

```
--max-size=10m
```

I would use this alltogether (max. 7.5MB of my 10MB bandwidth):

```
rsync -aP --max-size=10m --inplace user@remote.com:/pathto/remotefolder/ localfolder/
rsync -aP --bwlimit=7.5m --inplace user@remote.com:/pathto/remotefolder/ localfolder/
```

see [explainshell.com](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=rsync+-aP+--max-size%3D10m+--inplace+--bwlimit%3D7.5m)

Comment: you could just play the hidden file that rsync creates